# Transformation of JSON data in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a requirement wherein I have to convert JSON data from one format to other.
I have to fetch corresponding values of JSON array and make them a key value pair.

Below are the required details:

Input:

```
"Headers": {
    "Header": [
      {
        "Key": "SellerOrganization",
        "Value": "XYZ"
      },
      {
        "Key": "SellerType",
        "Value": "B2C"
      },
      {
        "Key": "Region",
        "Value": "SOUTH"
      },
      {
        "Key": "OrderType",
        "Value": "RETURN"
      },
      {
        "Key": "InvoiceType",
        "Value": ""
      },
      {
        "Key": "EventType",
        "Value": "Created"
      },
      {
        "Key": "EntryType",
        "Value": "Call Center"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    SellerOrganization:XYZ,
    SellerType: B2C,
    Region:SOUTH,
    OrderType:RETURN,
    InvoiceType:"",
    EventType:Created,
    EntryType:Call Center
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [dynamic object](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements) that it will basically do what you want.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    (payload.Headers.Header map ((item, index) -> {
        (item.Key): item.Value
    })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of `reduce` function here which will let you convert your array to an `key, value` pair object

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Header reduce ((item, acc = {}) -> acc ++ {
    (item.Key): item.Value
})
```